# Run JavaScript from C# ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to run a javascript function from the code behind in C#. I looked at many resourses on internet but so far no luck. This does not even work with a very simple sample code that I have:

Code behind:

```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"a","a();", true);
  }
```

In my aspx file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         function a()
         {
             var i = 0;

         }
  </script>
```

When I run this I get :

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'a' is undefined

Note :

Also tried :

- ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"a","a()", true);
- ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"a","a", true);

Still getting the same error.

**Note for the future reader: The trick is to use an ASP update panel. I did not found a single source to point to this very important fact.**

Comment: you should never use identifier with just 1 char `"a"`or naming object or methods like that. Now, first step to debug :  `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"myDebugAlert","alert('My script is OK');", true);` does it work? You may tell me yes , then I may tell you it is because your `a()` function does not exist when you script is registered StartupScript.

Comment: a is just for test. I tired to simplify my code here. 

And Yes I run this on the code behind directly`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"a","alert('test');", true)` it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript anywhere as long as it is inside an `UpdatePanel`

Now tell your `a()` is a javascript function :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"a","javascript:a();", true);
```

Comment: @Michal Hainc is right. The way I go (it is not universal receipt^^) is using `master page` (_for navigation and footer (don't need to refresh so often))_ and all my pages are content from this master page inside an update panel. Like that all my website can use ajax. **Right now, glad it is ok for you now. Thanks @Michal Hainc too. Hope you nice coding and fun!

Answer (score 2):

In your button click event handler, it is too late to register startup scripts. you have to do that sooner. See the asp.net page life cycle.

I did the same as you in `Page_Load` event, and it works flawlessly even with the `a()` identifier.  I have uploaded a working sample to my Onedrive public folder. See [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=ff0d3501437060e3!2447&authkey=!AMUUbAKyZ9SZ7Pw&ithint=file%2Czip). Look inside `default.aspx` and `default.cs` files.

default.aspx

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function a(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }

    </script>
```

default.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "a", "a('hello world');", true);
    }
```

Comment: Nice just copy my answer and treat me? I didn't disrespect (like you did toward me) I just give world widely admitted advice.

Comment: @  MacKentoch I don't see this as your answer at all. Your comment was not helpful at all.